# split a number into an array of strings

Tags: c#

There is a list of candidates.

```
candid: {12,14,16,19,25,64,78}
```

**Code :**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candid.Count; i++)
    {
        var searchTerm = candid[i].ToString();
        var searchItems = searchTerm.ToCharArray().ToString();
        foreach (Tran b in transactions)
        {
            string[] temp = new string[b.itemsUtilities.Count];
            int j = 0;
            foreach (ItemUtility c in b.itemsUtilities)
            {
                temp[j] = c.item.ToString();
                j = j + 1;
            }
            if (searchItems.All(a => temp.Contains(a)))
                arraye[i] = arraye[i] + (b.transactionUtility);
        }
    }
```

I receive the following error:

> 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best
>   extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable,
>   char)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

If code changed from : `var searchItems = searchTerm.ToCharArray().ToString();`

To : `var searchItems = searchTerm.split();`

This error is fixed, But this `split` command does not separate numbers.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: `searchTerm.ToCharArray().ToString()`. it will always return `"System.Char[]"` no matter what `searchTerm` was.

Comment: `using system.Linq` are you missing this

Comment: I believe you want to have a `string[] searchItems` but ended getting a `string searchItems` because of the `.ToCharArray().ToString()`

Comment: @Rahul The problem is bigger, the error message could be considered secondary in this particular problem

Comment: From my understanding searchTerm.All(a => temp.Contains(a)) will work too no need to cast a string into a string []

Comment: What value do you expect in `searchItems`?
Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and maybe we can help more.

Comment: Is it me or from a Int > string > Char array > string array, just  to check a contains look over kill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to separate the numbers into a `string[]`.

```
var searchItems = searchTerm.ToCharArray().ToString();
```

This will always create a single string `"System.Char[]"` so is not what you want.

I guess you want:

```
string[] searchItems = searchTerm.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

This should fix the compiler error because `searchItems.All` will now project strings and not chars.

Comment: The dangers of using `var` xD

Answer (score 0):

More that a simple missing include, I do think that you are over thinking

your code seems to be simplify as :

```
for (int i = 0; i < candid.Count; i++)
{
    var searchTerm = candid[i].ToString();

    foreach (Tran b in transactions)
    {       
        var tmp = b.itemsUtilities.Select(x=> x.item.ToString()).ToList(); 

        if( searchTerm.All(a=> tmp.Contains (a)){
            arraye[i] = arraye[i] + (b.transactionUtility);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can simplify again instead of for each you filter Trasanction based on the if condition. 
And if your candid is 11 no need to check twice for 1 so a simple Distinct() will help here.